# Counting PList keys at a specific level

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, plist

I'm trying to create a grouped tableview, but when it comes to the number rows in sections I haven't been able to get the correct values. From the list below 'OrdreLinje', 'OrdreStatus' and 'KundeLeveranse' are the sections and the items below would be the rows visible to the user. So the number of rows in the sections would be 4,1,1 respectively, my question is how do I count these keys to produce the correct result.

1. Root(Dict)

   - -->Rows(Array)

     - ---->Item 0(Dict)
     - ------>**OrdreLinje(Array)**
     - -------->item0(Dict)
     - -------->item1(Dict)
     - -------->item2(Dict)
     - -------->item3(Dict)
     - ------>**KundeLeveranse(Array)**
     - -------->item0(Dict)
     - ------>**OrdreStatus(Array)**
     - -------->item0(Dict)

Sorry, I did try to insert an image but i'm not reputable enough :)

Any help is greatly appreciated,
B

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting a count of the keys in the *first* dictionary in the Rows array, or the sum of the keys in *all* the dictionaries in the Rows array?

For the first, you could do:

```
NSArray *rows = [rootDict objectForKey:@"Rows"];
NSInteger count = 0;
if (rows.count > 0)
{
    NSDictionary *firstRow = [rows objectAtIndex:0];
    count = firstRow.allKeys.count;
}
```

If you want the count of all keys in all dictionaries in the Rows array, you could do:

```
NSArray *rows = [rootDict objectForKey:@"Rows"];
NSInteger count = 0;
for (NSDictionary *dict in rows)
{
    count += dict.allKeys.count;
}
```

Comment: Not quite, the lines in bold will be the sections, this part I have gotten right :) but the items under these are what I need to count in order to specify the number of rows in the sections. So the 'OrdreLinje' section should have 4 rows. So I need to count only the keys under 'OrdreLinje'. I should mention also that I called them keys as they are in the keys field in the plist, sorry for the confusion :)